# select distinct record from database

Tags: mysql

I want to display items on my page, which have minimum price from available same items.
This is my table sellingitem.

```
+-----------+--------+
| sellprice | code   |
+-----------+--------+
| 270       | SKU012 |
| 275       | SKU011 |
| 265       | SKU006 |
| 285       | SKU009 |
| 3900      | SKU007 |
| 4000      | SKU008 |
| 3799      | SKU007 |
+-----------+--------+
```

But I want to display only this records.

```
+-----------+--------+
| sellprice | code   |
+-----------+--------+
| 270       | SKU012 |
| 275       | SKU011 |
| 265       | SKU006 |
| 285       | SKU009 |
| 3799      | SKU007 |
| 4000      | SKU008 |
+-----------+--------+
```

So how can I do that?

Comment: post what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select min(sellprice) as sellprice ,code
from sellingitem
group by code
```

Answer (score 0):

> So tell me how can i do that?

OK Sir :)

```
SELECT code,MIN(sellprice)
FROM sellingitem
GROUP BY code
```

That picks up the minimum price for each product

**[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0921e/1)**

Comment: Thank u guruji(mentor). :)

Answer (score -1):

This one will do.

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
GROUP BY code
HAVING MIN(code)
```